# Problem with lstlinsting biblatex utf8 T1 and babel

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, listings, babel

I am a Spanish speaker. I have in my TeX file all the usual stuff for my language. Also I use lstlistings and now I want to use biblatex (ex bibtex user). However I can not get working together this two.... here the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{
\spanishdecimal{.}
}

\usepackage[
    style=numeric-comp,
    firstinits=true,
    sorting=none,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    eprint=false,
    backend=bibtex,
    maxnames=99
]{biblatex}

%\usepackage{listings}

\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
   Hola \cite{El-sayed2005}
   Buen día \cite{Voter2002a}
   \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

When I uncomment lstlistings I get the followin error:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/spanish.lbx)                                                                                                                                          

Package biblatex Warning: 'babel' detected but 'csquotes' missing.                                                                                                                             
(biblatex)                Loading 'csquotes' recommended.                                                                                                                                      

(./main.aux)                                                                                                                                                                                   

Package biblatex Warning: Data encoding is 'utf8'.                                                                                                                                             
(biblatex)                Use backend=biber.                                                                                                                                                   

No file main.bbl.                                                                                                                                                                              
(./main1-blx.bbl)                                                                                                                                                                              
./main.tex:33: Undefined control sequence.                                                                                                                                                     
<to be read again> \edef \lbx@tempa {m.z                                                                                                                                                       
                                        a.el-sayed}                                                                                                                                            
l.33 \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]                                                                                                                                               

./main.tex:33:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!                                                                                                                         
Transcript written on main.log.
```

What can I do? I need both packages... :S. Here the library.bib

```
@inproceedings{Voter2002a,
address = {San Juan, Puerto Rico, USA},
author = {Voter, Arthur F.},
booktitle = {Int. Conf. Comput. Nanosci. Nanotechnol.},
pages = {128 -- 131},
publisher = {Computational Pubns},
title = {{Introduction to the time scale problem}},
volume = {836},
year = {2002}
}
@article{El-sayed2005,
author = {El-Sayed, Ivan H and Huang, Xiaohua and El-Sayed, Mostafa A},
journal = {Nano Lett.},
number = {5},
pages = {829--834},
volume = {5},
year = {2005}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Errors or warnings? I don't have any errors, just warnings if I put the bib file in the same file using `filecontents`. Check the encoding of your files.

Comment: Thanks. Did you uncomment the line
`%\usepackage{listings}`??

Comment: I see now, that you also had only warnings (the same), but reffered to them as errors. Doesn't matter now, that it's solved. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `refsection` you have to run `bibtex` with the subfile:

```
bibtex <file>1-blx
```

the "1" indicates the `refsection`. You can see it the terminal output or the logfile which file should be run. In your above output it is `./main1-blx`:

```
bibtex main1-blx
```

creates the subbib.

However, you have a UTF-8 encoding. The reason why `backend=bibtex8` with running `bibtex8` or, the best solution, `backend=biber` (is the default) and running `biber`. `biber` can detect itself if there are subfiles.

And, of course, the main problem is the active character "." (the dot) in your document. Try

```
\usepackage[english,spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
```

and then:

```
\begin{refsection}
   Hola \cite{El-sayed2005}
   Buen día \cite{Voter2002a}
   \selectlanguage{english}
   \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
```

or

```
\foreignlanguage{english}{%
   \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]}
```